# error: undefined reference in JNI function After upgrading NDK and Cmake for Android Studio

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I reinstalled Android Studio and it upgrade NDK and CMake to the lastest ones. After that I got this error:

```
Error while executing process /home/wxh/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/wxh/AndroidStudioProjects/Measure_It/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target removebackground}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/removebackground.dir/src/main/cpp/removebackground.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library 

error: undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__ndk1::vector<int, std::__ndk1::allocator<int> > const&)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code compiles fine before so there is no typo in that.
To double check:

1. `imgproc.hpp` was included.
2. `CMakeList.txt` has include path and library path:

   ```
   include_directories(/home/wxh/Android/opencv_sdk/native/jni/include)
   add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
   set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/wxh/Android/opencv_sdk/native/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
   ```
3. app `build.gradle` has

   ```
       DefaultConfig{externalNativeBuild {
       cmake { cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 "
           arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
           abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'}}}
       externalNativeBuild { cmake { path "CMakeLists.txt"} }
   ```
4. It has nothing to do with opencv becuase it hasn't been altered.

What else could be wrong???

Comment: Possible reason: new NDK -> new compiler -> it differs from the one, used for compile openCV -> openCV library which you have is no longer compatible with the compiler. If this is true, then you need to rebuild OpenCV with your new compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV 3 was using gunstl which is no longer supported in NDK. The new releases of NDK have only `c++_static` and `c++_shared` STL. You can rebuild OpenCV 3.x from sources with a new release of NDK and choose one of supported STL options, or you can use OpenCV 4.x which comes prebuilt with `c++_static`.

It may be easier to fix your code to cover the API differences between 3.x and 4.x than to rebuild OpenCV from sources.

Comment: Congrats, that is the smoking gun.Problem resolved by download **android-ndk-r17c** change  **ndk.dir=/address_to/android-ndk-r17c** change cmake argument to **-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static**.I will not go for a total upgrade that smell like a source of overwhelming amount of errors if the current code works stick with it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not list stepping back to NDK r17 as one of the easy options, because your question was specifically about 'upgrading NDK'.

Comment: I did not upgrade NDK myself,there is only the most current one available at Android Studio.I build my opencv-sdk very long time ago cant remember how i did it.I dont think there is any compatible sdk for download right away.so i'll go for downgrade NDK unless there are any downside to consider.